Unable to set the customized product version in Azure DevOps pipeline
I'm trying to set the Product version as follows:

Major version-1
Minor version-0
Revision – builddate YYYYMMDD,

build-on the days count (1,2,3) but after pipeline execution it is getting overridden by .csproj in Azure DevOps YML script - example:
1.0.20240708.1

This is the Build command am using to accomplish the above.
- name: MSBuildArguments
  value: '/p:OutputPath="$(PackagePath)" /p:ProductVersion="$(ProductVersion)"   /p:FileVersion="$(fileVersion)" /p:Copyright="$(CopyrightText)" /p:ProductName="$(productname)"'

values came out properly when it was Write-Output but after pipeline execution, some random values gets generated.
But TFS has the inbuilt property for this to work without any extra commands. Trying to find the similar on azure.
- name: majorVersion
  value: 1
- name: minorVersion
  value: 0
- name: buildDate
  value: $[format('{0:yyyyMMdd}', pipeline.startTime)]
- name: buildCounter
  value: $[counter('BuildCounter', 1)]

$ProductVersion = "$majorVersion.$minorVersion.$buildDate.$buildCounter"


Glad to see you in Stack Overflow! The Build command you shared is not a task or command actually, but looks like a variable definition. Could you share more code snippet so it could be more clear?

See if this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59820867/558486

Thanks for reaching our Wade, here's the snippet:

task: VSBuild@1
displayName: 'Build Project Solution'
inputs:
solution: '$(buildSolution)'
msbuildArgs: '$(MSBuildArguments)'
platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'
createLogFile: true
logFileVerbosity: 'detailed'


@user26307134 add how you define $(ProductVersion) variable in your yaml.


name: majorVersion
value: 1
name: minorVersion
value: 0
name: buildDate
value: $[format('{0:yyyyMMdd}', pipeline.startTime)]
name: buildCounter
value: $[counter('BuildCounter', 1)]

$ProductVersion = "$majorVersion.$minorVersion.$buildDate.$buildCounter"

@beena it's hard to read those code snippets in the comments. Please edit your question and paste them there.

@RuiJarimba edited now.. pls check


build-on the days count (1,2,3) but after pipeline execution it is getting overridden by .csproj in Azure DevOps YML script

For the project  targets .NET Core or .NET Standard, if you have productversion defined in csproj, it will take precedence over the ones passed as MSBuild arguments.
sample below:

After i remove it from csproj, the MSBuild arguments works then. Hence, please try to move the properties from csproj.

